# Is there any way to have the legend text above the symbol and beside it, not just above?

Tags: qgis, legend

Is there any way to have the legend text above the symbol and beside it, not just above?

What i do at present is to cut the end of the text off and insert a label then group them, however i want to resize the box and possibly have the text go into two lines, or preferably wrap around the symbol.

Excuse the sloppy work below, a rush job for illustrative purposes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if I get it now: You have one layer with a long name and want to write part of the layer name above the symbol and part besides it, right?

By default the whole name is written above the symbol. In **Legend items** you can edit the entry and remove part of the name to then add it to the symbol as shown in the screen below: Both entries in the Legend items tree can be edited.

[image]